Protect my PHP Scripts from being pirated with a Licensing SaaS
As there it is very easy to illegally copy and share my web-software (developed in PHP), it's getting harder and harder to keep things safe.
We talk about bigger PHP Projects that should be saved from easy coping and installed multiple times on different servers. For sure nothing is 100% safe.
So how do I protect my software from piracy?
DRM, license management, or anything else is fine, I'd love to hear what works (or doesn't) for you.

Please say whether your software is desktop or mobile or webapp, and what OS(es). Otherwise the question is too general. Thanks!

Is your software developed in PHP or is PHP used to illegally copy software? It's not clear to me. If you're distributing PHP source code, there's nothing to prevent anyone from copying it. That's basically the same for every source code.

I don't think PHP would be used to copy some software. If it's about scraping then Python is a way more popular choice. This is a poorly asked question that likely means some PHP/JS/HTML software that is distributed with closed source. And since PHP is not compiled, it'd take few minutes for a decent developer to remove any sort of security from the code a.k.a. null it. Except maybe pulling some data from your server based on some API key, if that data is necessary for running the application.

If you want to prevent some non-technical users from copying it or sending it to their friends, which would reduce the piracy by a bit, that should be accurately stated in the question, also including info like if you're using any sort of a framework.

PHP is normally distributed in source code form and then interpreted for execution. However, if you distribute source code, anyone can easily remove those lines of code that are meant to protect your application.
So, like other languages, you need to compile your PHP code into a binary. There once was Hiphop by Facebook, which worked well, but is discontinued and they don't have a PHP compiler any more.
Today there still is PeachPie, the successor of Phalanger which compiles PHP to .NET.
Pros:

it uses the modern Roslyn platform, so this seems to get some support in the future
it's still actively maintained (as of 2024-08-24)

Cons:

it compiles to .NET. Not everyone can easily run .NET apps on their server.
it compiles to .NET. The IL code of .NET can still be reverse engineered quite easily. You may need additional steps like obfuscation.

If this does not work out for you, the correct search term would be "PHP transpiler".

If you want to prevent non-technical users from sharing your app, simply add any sort of a domain validation mechanism, e.g. with a key:

Allow the key to be entered in some kind of admin panel or config file of the software for e.g. only a single domain - which of course will need to do a request to your server, which then will check it in a database
And you will need some mechanism to provide users their unique keys on your website. You could add a changeable domain field to the form in case the owners could change their domains and be able to relink the key to another one in the future.
Do some periodic checks for the validity of the key, let's say daily - especially if you allow to change the domain on your site.
Lastly, disable functionalities of the software until a valid key is entered.
A slightly different and more robust version could use a login system to your website instead of the key. Or a license file. But it doesn't add much to the security, as you will need to validate the domain as the main check anyways, to prevent reusing the same account or file.

If you want to prevent piracy from more technical users, that's rather impossible, no matter if with PHP or anything else. Even the most secured software like Adobe Photoshop, with several layers of user/license validation, gets completely cracked or nulled at some point, by people who know how to reverse engineer software through various techniques, such as decompilation or network request sniffing. It depends on software's popularity more than anything else. Then a bunch of non-technical users will get access to the software with your checks removed anyways, as long as they know where to look - mainly on Torrent websites and other suspicious ones where they're likely to get viruses.

You are absolutely right, every Software can be nulled or cracked from a developer, only normal user shouldn’t be able to copy it easily. Maybe ther is a licensing server or a nice modern SaaS that do the job?

There are a bunch, I don't really see the point though, as you'll need to implement integration with those anyways, with not that much less code and potential vulnerabilities that come with it and that you can't know about without accurately reviewing the code.

If there is a bunch of it maybe there are customers of them they see a point.
